# How do I get the Dropdown component?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Canvas with a panel in it, and put bunch of Dropdown menus under the panel, along with a script.

In the script, I tried to obtain the Dropdown menus by

```
GetComponent<Dropdown>();
GetComponentInChildren<Dropdown>();
GameObject.Find("Range").GetComponent<Dropdown>();    //"Range" is the name of the Dropdown menu GameObject.
GetComponents<Dropdown>();
GetComponentsInChildren<Dropdown>();
GameObject.Find("Range").GetComponents<Dropdown>();    //"Range" is the name of the Dropdown menu GameObject.
.
.
.
```

And it "ALL" returned `null`!

Could somebody please be so kind and tell me where did I do wrong and teach me the correct way to do it, please!?

PS. I don't want to set each individual dropdown as an `[SerializeField]` and assign it in the inspector, for many reasons. Thanks for your understanding. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

First of all;

- Please check in the inspector and make sure that your script and the Dropdown component are in the same object. (note that you can add a Dropdown menu both as a UI element and a component)
- Also, make sure that you have the "UnityEngine.UI" reference in your script.

However, if you have a parent object and you're trying to get a list of Dropdown components of its children, then you should use "GetComponentsInChildren" in the parent object. You can find a detailed explanation and examples in [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html).

So, the code should be:

`UnityEngine.UI`

`Dropdown[] myDropDownList = GetComponentsInChildren<Dropdown>();`

P.S. For TextMeshPro - Dropdown element, TMPro namespace is needed. So, the code should be:

`UnityEngine.UI`

`TMPro.TMP_Dropdown[] myDropDownList = GetComponentsInChildren<TMPro.TMP_Dropdown>();`

or

`UnityEngine.UI`

`using TMPro;`

`TMP_Dropdown[] myDropDownList = GetComponentsInChildren<TMP_Dropdown>();`

Comment: I put the script under the Panel and add Dropdown menus under it as "UI elements". And I tried `GetComponentsInChildren` as my post said and returned **null**.

Comment: @PiggyChu001, I have created a panel and added 2 Dropdown UI elements under it. Then I wrote a code to test it (a script attached to the panel):

`Dropdown[] myDropDownList = GetComponentsInChildren<Dropdown>();`

This line didn't return null and I could iterate that list. If you did the same, make sure again that your script is attached to the right object, your Dropdown menus have the right parent and you have the  "UnityEngine.UI" reference. If you're still having a problem, make sure that you don't have any other errors in your other scripts. It may confuse the editor sometimes.

Comment: [Please take a look](https://imgur.com/a/AkLTWZ8). I don't understand why mine doesn't work!?

Comment: @PiggyChu001, in the second screenshot I can see that you have a TMP script, which means you're not using the normal Dropdown. For that special Dropdown, you have to access the TMPro namespace. So, the code should be: `TMPro.TMP_Dropdown[] ddd = GetComponentsInChildren<TMPro.TMP_Dropdown>();`